# Laravel multiple models same belongsTo relationship but with constraints?

Tags: php, database, laravel, orm, eloquent

I have a model `Status` which have a `name` attribute.

Further I have two (later maybe n) other Models which can have a `Status` assigned by a `belongsTo()` relationship.

Now I want to have constraints that model `A` could only have specific statuses and model `B` other specific statuses.

My problem is that I don´t know which would be a good design to enforce these constraints.

Of course I could have different models for statuses for `A` and `B` but I already have the status table and model B was added later.

I thought maybe I could add a model `AStatus` and `BStatus` and so on, which would have a foreign key to a `Status`, but then I don´t know how I would express this relationship in Laravel Eloquent.

Another option would be to add a attribute to the existing `Status` table which indicates which Model is allowed to have this status. But this doesn't feels like a good idea, because then I could not express that multiple Models could have the same status.

I hope you can help me!